# Find the limit of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\tan(\frac{2k}{n^2})$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\tan(\frac{2k}{n^2})$$ Now, i've wrote it like this :$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\frac{\sin\frac{2k}{n^2}}{\cos\frac{2k}{n^2}})$ and since nor sin or cos are monotone and are bounded by -1 and 1, i am thinking that the limit might by 1, but i am not sure ...

Comment: From the numerical side: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\tan(\frac{2k}{n^2}) = 1$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As $z$ is very small we use $\tan z \to z$.
$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \tan \frac{2k}{n^2} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2k}{n^2}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2k}{n} =\int_{0}^{1} 2xdx=1$$. Here we have taken $x=k/n$.

Comment: It should be noted that this works because the error made is on the order of $O(z^3)$.

Answer (score 3):

Using $\tan(x)=x+\mathcal O(x^3)$ as $x\to0$ and $\frac{2k}{n^2}\le\frac{2}{n}$, we get $$\tan\left(\frac{2k}{n^2}\right)=\frac{2k}{n^2}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)$$ as $n\to\infty$. Can you finish now?

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! The thing is i haven't learned yet taylor series... is there a highschool approach to it ?

Comment: @Jon9 Without Taylor you can do the same thing: Set $f(x)=\tan(x)-x$. Then $f'(x)=\tan^2(x)$ and by mean value Theorem: $$f(x)=x f'(\xi)=\mathcal O(x^3)$$ since $\xi\in[0,x]$

Comment: Thank you !  The judgement that i' ve stated in the beginning, do you think it is also correct ?

Comment: It was more of a intuition...

Comment: @Jon9 I don't think your intuition works since it would also apply if we had for example $4k$ instead of $2k$ but the sum would be $2$ instead of $1$

Comment: Thanks! I will keep that in mind !